# webpack v5 devtool should match pattern

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

Setting up a simple Middleman app utilizing webpack 5, but getting this invalid configuration object error:

```
[webpack-cli]
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.devtool should match pattern "^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$".
   BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5: The devtool option is more strict.
   Please strictly follow the order of the keywords in the pattern.
```

None of the [devtool options listed here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) seem to give any other error than the one above, nor does leaving out devtool or explicitly making it false.

This is the setup I had working with webpack 4, but would appreciate any insight into what could unblock the invalid configuration error.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack5_practice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.3",
    "webpack": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    site: ['./source/javascripts/site.js'],
    style: ['./source/stylesheets/site.css.scss'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.tmp/dist'),
    filename: '[name].min.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],
};
```

My config.rb w/ regards to webpack

```
# Webpack
activate :external_pipeline,
  name: :webpack,
  command: build? ? './node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --bail' : './node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch -d',
  source: "./dist",
  latency: 1
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Answering my own question and editing the original to include my error:

I was running Webpack through the Middleman external pipeline with the `-d` flag in config.rb. Removing the flag (or explicitly listing a devtool option) would fix the error.

Comment: Thank you. It worked but I don't understand the principle. Why the -d flag would prevent it from working 

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe this -d (or --devtool) is awaiting in the command line the proper options.

Comment: This answer has saved me! I can confirm that it works.